# Bare-bones pdf viewer that works with Amethyst tiling (macOS)

Tags: pdf, macos, tiling-wm, zathura

I want to have a bare-bones pdf viewer like zathura or mupdf-gl which can display a pdf, tile successfully with the window manager Amethyst, and be navigable with vim bindings.

I'm not wedded to any particular app or solution; advice of any kind is appreciated.

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.2 and can't get this to work. When I try zathura, Amethyst will not tile properly:

[image]

When I use mupdf-gl, tiling is successful but the document will not fill the window. I've tried reinstalling xquartz and mupdf and the problem persists. This problem does not appear on my friend's system running Mojave.

[image]

Comment: The [manual](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mupdf-gl.html) says that you can press 'W' to fit page width to window. Does that work for you?

Comment: It does not; the largest you can get the pdf to render on my machine is precisely one quarter of the window it is opened in. Resizing the window will truncate or reveal more of the pdf according to this rule.

Comment: Zathura is known for not working well with tiling windows managers: see https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura/issues/38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Zathura with Homebrew using zegervdv/zathuras repo, they recently added tilling window manager support.

Check out the GitHub update [here](https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura).

It works for me with Amethyst 0.15.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.